# Form invalidad in Django - ManyToMany relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to insert data in my ManyToMany relationship but i don't get it, my form always is invalidad.

I get this error when i try to save the form "The view apps.alumno.views.SubirActividad didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Models:

```
class Alumno(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nocontrol = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    grupo = models.ForeignKey(Grupo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.nocontrol)

class Actividad(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    asignatura = models.ForeignKey(Asignatura, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    alumno = models.ManyToManyField(Alumno, through='ActividadAlumno', through_fields=('actividad', 'alumno'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.nombre)

class ActividadAlumno(models.Model):
    actividad = models.ForeignKey(Actividad, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    alumno = models.ForeignKey(Alumno, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    documento = models.FileField(upload_to='asignatura/tarea/')
    calificacion = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Form:

```
class ActividadAlumnoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = ActividadAlumno

        fields = [
            'actividad',
            'alumno',
            'documento',
            'calificacion',
        ]
        labels = {
            'actividad': 'Fecha de entrega',
            'alumno': 'Entregado',
            'documento': 'Estado',
            'calificacion': 'Calificacion',
        }
        widgets = {
            'actividad': forms.Select(),
            'alumno': forms.Select(),
            'documento': forms.ClearableFileInput(),
            'calificacion': forms.NumberInput(),
        }
```

View:

```
def SubirActividad(request, id_actividad):
    actividad = Actividad.objects.get(id=id_actividad)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = ActividadAlumnoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('alumno:asignatura_detalle', clave=form.instance.asignatura.clave)
    else:
        alumno = Alumno.objects.get(user=request.user)
        form = ActividadAlumnoForm(initial={'actividad': actividad, 'alumno':alumno})
        return render(request, 'alumno/actividad_subir.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Probably the form is not valid, you aren't handling that case.

Comment: Yes the form is not valid but that's always and i never can save the data

Comment: What error does it produce?